# How can I download html5 canvas drawing as image

Tags: javascript, html, css, download, html5-canvas

I just recently uploaded my code files to a server. My website is a simple html5 drawing application where users are able to draw freely. I have this part done fine, however I am looking to implement a download button that simply downloads whatever the user has drawn as an image directly to their device i.e. phone, table, desktop. I have been looking for solutions to this for hours now and cant find anything. Is it a problem with my server? or anything like that? any help would be much appreciated. Below is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Elemental</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">



<style type="text/css">

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat+Alternates');

@media screen and (max-width: 425px){

html,body{
overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}






canvas { border: 3px solid #0BF446;
border-radius: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 35px; 
background-color:#313131;
position: relative;}

#download{background-color:#04A12B ;
border-radius: 0 15px 0 15px;
padding: 20px 40px;
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
font-size: 14px;
margin-top: 35px;
color: white;
font-family: 'Montserrat Alternates', sans-serif;}



#clearbutton{background-color:#04A12B ;
border-radius: 0 15px 0 15px;
padding: 20px;
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
font-size: 14px;
color: white;
font-family: 'Montserrat Alternates', sans-serif;
margin-top: 35px;}






</style>

</head>
<body>
<body onload="init()">
<a href="../homepage.html"><img src="minilogo.png" id ="logo"></a>


<canvas id="c" width="350px" height="350px"></canvas>


<button id = "download">Download</button>


<input type = "submit" value="Clear Sketchpad" id="clearbutton" onclick="clearCanvas(canvas,ctx);">







<script>

function init() {
        // Get the specific canvas element from the HTML document
        canvas = document.getElementById('c');

      }



function midPointBtw(p1, p2) {
  return {
    x: p1.x + (p2.x - p1.x) / 2,
    y: p1.y + (p2.y - p1.y) / 2
  };
}

function getPattern() {
  return ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
}


var el = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = el.getContext('2d');

ctx.lineWidth = 30;
ctx.lineJoin = ctx.lineCap = 'round';

var img = new Image;
img.onload = function() {
  ctx.strokeStyle = getPattern();
};
img.src = "https://i.postimg.cc/rF2R0GRY/dick2.png";

var isDrawing, points = [];



var getXY = function(e) {
  var source = e.touches ? e.touches[0] : e;

  return {
    x: source.clientX,
    y: source.clientY
  };
};







var startDrawing = function(e) {
  isDrawing = true;
  points.push(getXY(e));
  event.preventDefault();


};


var keepDrawing = function(e) {
  if (!isDrawing) return;

  points.push(getXY(e));
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

  var p1 = points[0];
  var p2 = points[1];

  ctx.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);

  for (var i = 1, len = points.length; i < len; i++) {
    var midPoint = midPointBtw(p1, p2);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(p1.x, p1.y, midPoint.x, midPoint.y);
    p1 = points[i];
    p2 = points[i + 1];
  }
  ctx.lineTo(p1.x, p1.y);
  ctx.stroke();
  event.preventDefault();
};


var stopDrawing = function() {
  isDrawing = false;
  points = [];

};






el.addEventListener('touchstart', startDrawing);
el.addEventListener('mousedown', startDrawing);

el.addEventListener('touchmove', keepDrawing);
el.addEventListener('mousemove', keepDrawing);

el.addEventListener('touchend', stopDrawing);
el.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDrawing);

function clearCanvas(canvas,ctx) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.beginPath()
    }




</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This might be what you're looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas#Saving_images

Comment: [canvas.toDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Canvas#toDataURL` method to generate a URL containing all the data of the canvas's current image. This can then be used in place of any URL -- a link's `href`, a `window.open`, etc. For a download link, you can use the `download` attribute on a link, which is an HTML5 addition. The value of the `download` attribute is the filename that will be used as the default save filename.

So to put all that together:

```
<a id='downloadLink' download='myDrawing.png'>Download Image</a>
<script>
    function createDownload() {
        const downloadURL = document.getElementById('c').toDataURL();
        document.getElementById('downloadLink').href = downloadURL;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your post. I tried this and it worked fine up until the point after the file has been downloaded. Once the file has been downloaded its unable to opened as an image, it keeps saying "does not support this file type" even though the image is meant to be a PNG? What could be the problem here? Im not sure